# Ionic: Using a custom PNG icon in Ion-refresher

Tags: css, icons, png, ionic-framework

Is it possible to change the default icon of the ion-refresher directive with a custom PNG icon ? I've looked at [this thread](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/customizing-infinite-scroll-pull-to-refresh-icons/1664/14) based on which I created a custom directive, but I can't integrate a PNG icon into it.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

There's lots to choose from out of the box http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/

Ionic uses animated SVGs, having switched over from font icons. They also have some Javascript running to cover older versions of Android - that link should explain it. If you still want to roll your own refresh spinner it sounds pretty complex and you might be better off posting a question on Ionic forums.